# Why is "carousel" in this page not working?

Tags: carousel

i've tried a Bootstrap-Carousel in this Page: http://www.karsten-heimer.de/Medien_121.html

The Carousel is not working, it shows only the first of two pictures... What do i wrong?

Greetings...

Edit: Bootstrap should be Version 5.

This is the code:

```html
<p></p>
<H2 align='center'><p><a name=114></a>Wolfgang Krege - Handbuch der Weisen von Mittelerde</p></H2>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<Title>Medium-Details Handbuch der Weisen von Mittelerde</Title>
<META NAME="author" CONTENT="Wolfgang Krege">
<META NAME="description" CONTENT="{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\fswiss MS Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 Wolfgang Krege, der sich seit Jahren mit Mittelerde, mit ihrer Geographie, ihren Sprachen und Liedern besch\'e4ftigt, hat anhand der Quellen ein Handbuch zusammengestellt, welches das Wissen des Rats der Weisen - soweit es uns \'fcberliefert ist - darstellt und kommentiert.\f1\par
}
">
<META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="Wolfgang Krege, , Handbuch der Weisen von Mittelerde, 3-608-93521-5, Klett-Cotta, Bücherliste von Karsten Heimer">
<META NAME="revisit-after" CONTENT="30 days">
<META NAME="content-language" CONTENT="de">
<META NAME="copyright" CONTENT="Karsten Heimer">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div class="card-Group h-75">
<div class="card mb-3" Style="max-width:450px;">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-header">Buchinformationen</h5>
<ul class="List-Group List-Group-flush">
<li class="List-Group-Item">Autor: Wolfgang Krege</li>
<li class="List-Group-Item">Kategorie: </li>
<li class="List-Group-Item">Verlag: Klett-Cotta</li>
<li class="List-Group-Item">ISBN: 3-608-93521-5</li>
<li class="List-Group-Item">
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img src="Tolkien_Handbuch.jpg" class="d-block w-75" alt="Buchcover">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img src="Krege_Handbuch_Mittelerde_Back.JPG" class="d-block w-75" alt="Buchbackcover">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card mb-3">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-header">Leseprobe</h5>
<p></p>
<div>Wolfgang Krege, der sich seit Jahren mit Mittelerde, mit ihrer Geographie, ihren Sprachen und Liedern beschäftigt, hat anhand der Quellen ein Handbuch zusammengestellt, welches das Wissen des Rats der Weisen - soweit es uns überliefert ist - darstellt und kommentiert.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='container-sm'>
<a target='_blank' href=http://www.karsten-heimer.de>Zurück zur Übersicht</a>
Impressum: Karsten Heimer, 82178 Puchheim, Oskar-Maria-Graf Str. 1, Mail: kh -at- karsten-heimer.de, Datenschutz: Diese Seite verwendet keine Cookies.
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Can you include your code in the question? also mention which version of Bootstrap you are using.

Comment: Code added, Bootstrap should be Version 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have wrong the included versions, also normally you should put the Javascript scripts at the end of the body tag:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<Title>Medium-Details Handbuch der Weisen von Mittelerde</Title>
<META NAME="author" CONTENT="Wolfgang Krege">
<META NAME="description" CONTENT="{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\fswiss MS Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 Wolfgang Krege, der sich seit Jahren mit Mittelerde, mit ihrer Geographie, ihren Sprachen und Liedern besch\'e4ftigt, hat anhand der Quellen ein Handbuch zusammengestellt, welches das Wissen des Rats der Weisen - soweit es uns \'fcberliefert ist - darstellt und kommentiert.\f1\par
}
">
<META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="Wolfgang Krege, , Handbuch der Weisen von Mittelerde, 3-608-93521-5, Klett-Cotta, Bücherliste von Karsten Heimer">
<META NAME="revisit-after" CONTENT="30 days">
<META NAME="content-language" CONTENT="de">
<META NAME="copyright" CONTENT="Karsten Heimer">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div class="card-Group h-75">
<div class="card mb-3" Style="max-width:450px;">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-header">Buchinformationen</h5>
<ul class="List-Group List-Group-flush">
<li class="List-Group-Item">Autor: Wolfgang Krege</li>
<li class="List-Group-Item">Kategorie: </li>
<li class="List-Group-Item">Verlag: Klett-Cotta</li>
<li class="List-Group-Item">ISBN: 3-608-93521-5</li>
<li class="List-Group-Item carousel">
<!-- Bootstrap v5 carousel from bootstrap documentation --> 
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="First Slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="Second Slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="Third Slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>


</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card mb-3">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-header">Leseprobe</h5>
<p></p>
<div>Wolfgang Krege, der sich seit Jahren mit Mittelerde, mit ihrer Geographie, ihren Sprachen und Liedern beschäftigt, hat anhand der Quellen ein Handbuch zusammengestellt, welches das Wissen des Rats der Weisen - soweit es uns überliefert ist - darstellt und kommentiert.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='container-sm'>
<a target='_blank' href=http://www.karsten-heimer.de>Zurück zur Übersicht</a>
Impressum: Karsten Heimer, 82178 Puchheim, Oskar-Maria-Graf Str. 1, Mail: kh -at- karsten-heimer.de, Datenschutz: Diese Seite verwendet keine Cookies.
</div>
<!-- JS Imports go here, and I've only included the bundle which contains all the required JS for bootstrap 5 to work -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here you have a fiddle working with the latest version of Bootstrap:

https://jsfiddle.net/53zjbf0p/1/

Comment: This was perfect. It works. Thank you and Greetings...